# Draw lines between points(multiple)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

with the help i am able to draw circle with the coordinated using:

```
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 5.0);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context,[UIColor grayColor].CGColor);
    /**** Get values from reponse and fill it in this array.   ******/
    NSArray *objectCoords = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"{{20,80},{5,5}}", @"{{120,60},{5,5}}", @"{{60,84},{5,5}}", @"{{80,88},{5,5}}", @"{{100,93},{5,5}}", @"{{20,20},{5,5}}", @"{{160,70},{5,5}}", @"{{128,68},{5,5}}", @"{{90,60},{5,5}}", @"{{110,80},{5,5}}", nil];
    for (NSString* objectCoord in objectCoords) {
        CGRect coord = CGRectFromString(objectCoord);
        // Draw using your coord
        CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, coord);
    }
```

Now what i am trying to achieve is draw lines between the points(circle),as shown in the attached image.I know we can draw a line between 2 points, but here in this case, the lines needs to be drawn between one to multiple point/circle .Please suggest me to achieve this result.
[image: expected output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just draw multiple lines. First, come up with a model to represent between which points you want to draw lines. For example, you could have an array of lines, where each line is defined, itself, as an array with the indices of two points, the starting point and the ending point.

For example, if you want to draw lines from point 1 to 3, 4, and 5, and from point 3 to 4 and 5, and between 4 and 5, you could do something like:

```
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1.0);

NSArray *lines = @[@[@(1), @(3)],
                   @[@(1), @(4)],
                   @[@(1), @(5)],
                   @[@(3), @(4)],
                   @[@(3), @(5)],
                   @[@(4), @(5)]];

for (NSArray *points in lines) {
    NSInteger startIndex = [points[0] integerValue];
    NSInteger endIndex   = [points[1] integerValue];

    CGRect startRect = CGRectFromString(objectCoords[startIndex]);
    CGRect endRect   = CGRectFromString(objectCoords[endIndex]);

    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, CGRectGetMidX(startRect), CGRectGetMidY(startRect));
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, CGRectGetMidX(endRect), CGRectGetMidY(endRect));
}

CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathStroke);
```

There are tons of different ways of doing it, but just come up with some model that represents where you want to draw the lines, and then iterate through that model to draw all of the individual lines.

---

If you wanted to have every point draw lines to the three closest points (which is not what your picture does, but it's what you asked for in a subsequent comment), you can:

- build array of indices, `indices` in your `objectCoords` array; and
- now iterate through each point in `objectCoords`:

  - build new array of indices, `sortedIndices`, sorted by the distance that the point represented by that index is from the current object in `objectCoords`; and
  - draw the three closest lines.

Thus:

```
// build array of indices (0, 1, 2, ...)

NSMutableArray *indices = [NSMutableArray array];
[objectCoords enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    [indices addObject:@(idx)];
}];

// now go through all of the points in objectCoords

[objectCoords enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

    // build new array of indices sorted by distance from the current point

    NSArray *sortedIndices = [indices sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
        CGFloat distance1 = [self distanceFromPointAtIndex:idx
                                            toPointAtIndex:[obj1 integerValue]
                                         usingObjectCoords:objectCoords];

        CGFloat distance2 = [self distanceFromPointAtIndex:idx
                                            toPointAtIndex:[obj2 integerValue]
                                         usingObjectCoords:objectCoords];

        if (distance1 < distance2)
            return NSOrderedAscending;
        else if (distance1 > distance2)
            return NSOrderedDescending;
        return NSOrderedSame;
    }];

    // now draw lines to the three closest indices
    // (skipping 0, because that's probably the current point)

    for (NSInteger i = 1; i < 4 && i < [sortedIndices count]; i++) {

        NSInteger index = [sortedIndices[i] integerValue];

        CGRect startRect = CGRectFromString(objectCoords[idx]);
        CGRect endRect   = CGRectFromString(objectCoords[index]);

        CGContextMoveToPoint(context,    CGRectGetMidX(startRect), CGRectGetMidY(startRect));
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, CGRectGetMidX(endRect),   CGRectGetMidY(endRect));
    }
}];

CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1);
CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathStroke);
```

And this uses the following method to calculate the distance between two points:

```
- (CGFloat)distanceFromPointAtIndex:(NSInteger)index1 toPointAtIndex:(NSInteger)index2 usingObjectCoords:(NSArray *)objectCoords
{
    CGRect rect1 = CGRectFromString(objectCoords[index1]);
    CGRect rect2 = CGRectFromString(objectCoords[index2]);

    return hypotf(CGRectGetMidX(rect1) - CGRectGetMidX(rect2), CGRectGetMidY(rect1) - CGRectGetMidY(rect2));
}
```

Using the `objectCoords` in your original example, that yields:

[image: points with lines b/w three closest for each]

Comment: Thanks Rob, this looks like on the track.Like you have an NSArray of line, giving values  to draw for ex: 1-3, in my array, i can't define that.I m trying to find the start and end point on the basis of nearest circle.any way to do that?

Comment: @iscavengers I'm not entirely sure I follow what you mean by "on the basis of the nearest circle." From each circle, find the nearest neighbor and draw a line to that? That's not what your diagram is doing, but, sure, you could do that. The above code sample illustrates all the basic components (e.g. using `CGRectGetMidX` and `CGRectGetMidY` to get the centers; how to draw the individual lines; etc.). To calculate distances between points, you can use `hypotf(point1.x - point2.x, point1.y - point2.y)`. So just iterate through the points, calculating distances, and the find the closest.

Comment: thanks for the response @Rob. in your ex : @(1), @(3) , (1), @(4)  drawing line from (1) to 3,4   how can i make it dynamic, from each individual point, it should draw line to atleast nearby 3-4 points?

Comment: @iscavengers I've added code sample that does that, but admittedly that's not the logic that your picture employed. It's not entirely obvious what logic is being used there to determine what lines are drawn.

Comment: This is so cool.that is one of the best approach.Thanks for making it so easy to understand.Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a little unrelated to your original question, but rather than an array of strings, like so:

```
NSArray *objectCoords = @[@"{{20,80},{5,5}}",
                          @"{{120,60},{5,5}}",
                          @"{{60,84},{5,5}}",
                          @"{{80,88},{5,5}}",
                          @"{{100,93},{5,5}}",
                          @"{{20,20},{5,5}}",
                          @"{{160,70},{5,5}}",
                          @"{{128,68},{5,5}}",
                          @"{{90,60},{5,5}}",
                          @"{{110,80},{5,5}}"];
```

I might suggest employing an array of `NSValue` objects:

```
NSArray *objectCoords = @[[NSValue valueWithCGRect:CGRectMake(20,80,5,5)],
                          [NSValue valueWithCGRect:CGRectMake(120,60,5,5)],
                          [NSValue valueWithCGRect:CGRectMake(60,84,5,5)],
                          [NSValue valueWithCGRect:CGRectMake(80,88,5,5)],
                          [NSValue valueWithCGRect:CGRectMake(100,93,5,5)],
                          [NSValue valueWithCGRect:CGRectMake(20,20,5,5)],
                          [NSValue valueWithCGRect:CGRectMake(160,70,5,5)],
                          [NSValue valueWithCGRect:CGRectMake(128,68,5,5)],
                          [NSValue valueWithCGRect:CGRectMake(90,60,5,5)],
                          [NSValue valueWithCGRect:CGRectMake(110,80,5,5)]];
```

Then, when you're extracting the `CGRect` value, instead of:

```
CGRect rect = CGRectFromString(objectCoords[index]);
```

You would do:

```
CGRect rect = [objectCoords[index] CGRectValue];
```

I know this looks more cumbersome, but using `NSValue` is going to be more efficient (which is useful when doing a lot or repeated calculations of distances).

---

Even better, you might want to define your own model object that more intuitively defines a point that you want to chart, e.g.:

```
@interface ChartPoint : NSObject

@property (nonatomic) CGPoint center;
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat radius;

@end
```

and

```
@implementation ChartPoint

+ (instancetype) chartPointWithCenter:(CGPoint)center radius:(CGFloat)radius
{
    ChartPoint *chartPoint = [[ChartPoint alloc] init];
    chartPoint.center = center;
    chartPoint.radius = radius;

    return chartPoint;
}

- (CGFloat)distanceToPoint:(ChartPoint *)otherPoint
{
    return hypotf(self.center.x - otherPoint.center.x, self.center.y - otherPoint.center.y);
}

@end
```

And then you can create an array of them like so:

```
NSArray *objectCoords = @[[ChartPoint chartPointWithCenter:CGPointMake(20,80)  radius:5],
                          [ChartPoint chartPointWithCenter:CGPointMake(120,60) radius:5],
                          [ChartPoint chartPointWithCenter:CGPointMake(60,84)  radius:5],
                          [ChartPoint chartPointWithCenter:CGPointMake(80,88)  radius:5],
                          [ChartPoint chartPointWithCenter:CGPointMake(100,93) radius:5],
                          [ChartPoint chartPointWithCenter:CGPointMake(20,20)  radius:5],
                          [ChartPoint chartPointWithCenter:CGPointMake(160,70) radius:5],
                          [ChartPoint chartPointWithCenter:CGPointMake(128,68) radius:5],
                          [ChartPoint chartPointWithCenter:CGPointMake(90,60)  radius:5],
                          [ChartPoint chartPointWithCenter:CGPointMake(110,80) radius:5]];
```

But this

- avoids inefficient `CGRectFromString`;
- avoids needing to do those repeated `CGRectGetMidX` and `CGRectGetMidY` calls to determine the center of the `CGRect`; and, most importantly,
- more accurately represents what your objects really are.

Obviously, when you want to draw your points, instead of doing:

```
NSString *string = objectCoords[idx];
CGRect   *rect = CGRectFromString(string);
CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, rect);
```

You'd do:

```
ChartPoint *point = objectCoords[idx];
CGContextAddArc(context, point.center.x, point.center.y, point.radius, 0, M_PI * 2.0, YES);
```

Comment: right, using CGRectFromString may be in appropriate.Thanks again for the help Rob.

Comment: one more thing Rob, i am trying to delay drawing lines, like first show the dots and after 3 sec, show the connecting lines. i put dots code in drawRect and your line drawing code in another method(callDrawlines), when i do [self callDrawline], it is called, but when i call it using selector, by giving 3 sec delay, it is not drawing line.any idea?

Comment: @iscavengers You cannot call these Core Graphics calls outside of the context of `drawRect`. So, you need to configure your `drawRect` such that it can either draw just the dots or draw both the dots and the lines, based upon the setting of some boolean variable. You then load the view (which by default should draw just the dots) and three seconds later set the boolean and then call `setNeedsDisplay` (which will result in having the `drawRect` called again).

Comment: :could u please help me out on this?

Comment: @iscavengers Sure, see https://github.com/robertmryan/PointsAndLines for working example.

Comment: Rob,thanks for putting this together for me,appreciate that, i wish i can give +100000.Is there any way i can send you a file?

Comment: @iscavengers Thank you, but it's really not necessary. Happy coding.